# Find the number of ordered pairs of positive integers (x,y) that satisfy $x^{2} - xy + y^{2} = 49$

Tags: polynomials

I tried to start this quest but won't end up with any answer.
First I made a complete square on RHS which is like this 
$x^{2} - xy - xy + xy + y^{2}$
Then converted it into
$xy+{\left( x - y\right) }^{2}$
And as LHS is a perfect square 
Which is $7^2$
So RHS must be a square but I don't know how to proceed further?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $x=y$, then $x=y=7$. So suppose $x>y$ (the other case is obviously symmetric). Notice that the equation can be rearranged as $x(x-y)=(7-y)(7+y)$, so $y<7$. Hence, you just have to check $6$ cases.

Comment: Maybe add a sentence why the rearranged equation lets you conclude $y>7$?

Comment: Oh, it's because the LHS is larger than $0$, so the factors in the RHS have to be either both positive or both negative: but they cannot be both negative, since $7+y>0$. So $7-y>0$, as we wanted.

Comment: Put that comment into your answer and your solution will be even nicer :-)

Comment: Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

Do this. Multiply both sides by $4$:
$$
x^2-xy+y^2=49\Rightarrow (2x-y)^2+3y^2 =196. 
$$
Now, this immediately yields, $y^2\leqslant \frac{196}{3}<66$, thus, $y\leqslant 8$. The rest is easy.